Is it true that $(a+b-c)^x+(b+c-a)^x+(c+a-b)^x\ge a^x+b^x+c^x$, for $a$, $b$, $c$ the sides of a triangle, and $|x|>1$?
Let $(a,b,c)$ be the sides of a triangle. Experimental evidences show that in any triangle, if $|x| > 1$ then
$$
(a+b-c)^x + (b+c-a)^x + (c+a-b)^x \ge a^x + b^x + c^x \tag 1
$$
with equality trivially holding in case the triangle is equilateral triangles or if $x = 0,1$. If $|x| < 1$ the above inequality reverses.
Can this be proved or disproved?

This equality is true, and I'll prove when $x$ is positive. The proof of negative case can be obtained by changing $x$ to $\left\vert x \right\vert$.
Let $a=p+q, b=q+r, c=r+p$ (Ravi substitution)
The equality is then equivalent to $(2p)^x+(2q)^x+(2r)^x\geq (p+q)^x+(q+r)^x+(r+p)^x$. It sufficies to prove that $2^{x-1}(p^x+q^x)\geq (p+q)^x$, because if you change $p,q$ to $q,r$ or $r,p$ and add them you get the desired inequality.  $2^{x-1}(p^x+q^x)\geq (p+q)^x$ is equivalent to $(1^x+1^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}(1^x+1^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdots (1^x+1^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}(p^x+q^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\geq (p+q)$  where $(1^x+1^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ multiplicated $x-1$ times, which is true because of Hölder inequality.
